# Grouping & summarizing data frame by multiple different columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, group-summaries

I don't know if I am not searching with the right terms but I can't find a post about this.

I have a df :

```
df <- data.frame(grouping_letter = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'), grouping_animal = c('Cat', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Dog'), value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

I want to group by `grouping_letter` and by `grouping_animal`. I want to do this using `dplyr`.

If I did it separately, it would be :

```
df %>% group_by(grouping_letter) %>% summarise(sum(value))

df %>% group_by(grouping_animal) %>% summarise(sum(value))
```

Now let's say, I have hundreds of columns I need to group by individually. How can I do this?

I was trying:

`results <- NULL
    for (i in grouping_columns) {
        results[[i]] <- df %>% group_by(df$i) %>% summarize(sum(value))
    }`

I got a list called results with the output. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this instead of using a for-loop?

Answer (score 2):

We can create an index of 'grouping' colums (using `grep`), loop over the index (with `lapply`) and separately get the `sum` of 'value' after grouping by the column in the 'index'.

```
 library(dplyr)
 i1 <- grep('grouping', names(df))
 lapply(i1, function(i) 
        df[setdiff(seq_along(df), i)] %>% 
                     group_by_(.dots=names(.)[1]) %>% 
                     summarise(Sumvalue= sum(value)))
#[[1]]
#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]

#  grouping_animal Sumvalue
#           (fctr)    (dbl)
#1             Cat        9
#2             Dog       12

#[[2]]
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

#  grouping_letter Sumvalue
#           (fctr)    (dbl)
#1               A        3
#2               B        7
#3               C       11
```

---

Or we can do this by converting the dataset from 'wide' to 'long' format, then group by the concerned columns and get the `sum` of 'value'.

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df, Var, Group, -value) %>% 
         group_by(Var, Group) %>% 
         summarise(Sumvalue = sum(value))
#              Var Group Sumvalue
#            (chr) (chr)    (dbl)
#1 grouping_animal   Cat        9
#2 grouping_animal   Dog       12
#3 grouping_letter     A        3
#4 grouping_letter     B        7
#5 grouping_letter     C       11
```

Comment: I'm trying it on a df of 11M rows, 12 value cols and 6 grouping vars . Taking really long - for-loop completed much faster !

Comment: @vagabond Then, converting from 'wide' to 'long' may take a bit of time compared to the loop method.  Have you tried the `lapply` option?

Comment: not yet . . i know it will shoot the memory! I'm on 8GB RAM :-)